# How to add image on calendar control in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am new to the Windows phone application development, I am using windows phone 7 calendar control in my application. I want to add a small image on a cell of calendar on particular date. Is it possible to do with available calendar control?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with current calendar control.